# When is a metrizable topological vector space locally bounded?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Consider a topological vector space $E$ with topology $\sigma$. Suppose that $E$ is metrizable, in other words, that there exists a metric $d$ on $E$ that induces the topology $\sigma$. One can then define two distinct notions of boundedness for subsets of $E$.

First, a subset $B$ of $E$ is called *$d$-bounded* if it is a subset of a ball of bounded radius for $d$. However, $B$ may also be bounded with respect to the topology $\sigma$, which we shall call *topologically bounded*. For a topological vector space, this means that for every open neighbourhood $U$ of the origin, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $\delta B = \{\delta x \mid x \in B\}$ is a subset of $U$. (A $d$-bounded subset of $E$ need not be topologically bounded. For example, the metric $d' = d / (1+d)$ induces the same topology on $E$ as $d$, but the whole space $E$ is $d'$-bounded.)

The topological vector space $E$ is called *locally bounded* if there exists an open neighbourhood of $0$ that is topologically bounded. What conditions need to be imposed on a metrizable topological vector space $E$ for it to become locally bounded? In particular, is it true for every locally convex metrizable $E$? Since the open balls of finite radius form a basis of neighbourhoods around $0$, this can be rephrased as follows: under what conditions on $E$ is there an $r > 0$ such that $B_d(r)$ is topologically bounded?

Comment: I believe this is exactly a characterisation of normed spaces among metrizable topological vector spaces. It fails for locally convex spaces, as shows by $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Adde: this is true for locally convex topologically vector spaces. So a locally convex topological vector space is locally bounded iff it is normable. E.g see http://www.ma.huji.ac.il/~razk/iWeb/My_Site/Teaching_files/TVS.pdf

Comment: The locally convex case is one of the first theorems in the theory of topological vector spaces. It is due to Kolmogorov (but nowadays a simple exercise).

Comment: I presume that there is no interesting link between metrizability and local boundedness. Henno, If you want to submit your comment as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.